# Timestamp on GoogleSpreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a code work for specific sheets in a Google Spreadsheets the code is set to work on a specific sheet, could this be done with an array or would that create a problem here is what I have:

Original Code:

```
function onEdit() {
  // writes the current date to the last cell on the row when a cell in a specific column is edited
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 20;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch) {
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
    targetCell.setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
  }
}
```

Thi is what I've been trying (currently not working)

```
function onEdit() {
  var repArray  = new Array();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i in allSheets) {                              
  if ((allSheets[i].getName()).match(/.*?\.$/))
      {repArray.push(allSheets[i].getName());}
 }
  var sheetArray = [];
  for (var j in repArray) {
  var tempSheet  = ss.getSheetByName(repArray[j]);
  var sheetNameToWatch = "tempSheet";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 11

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch) {
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1); // I choose 1 because the Date Stamp should be placed in Column A 
    targetCell.setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy"));
  }
}
```

This spreadsheet is worked on by different reps each has a Sheet with their names (and a period at the end to build the Array) so when someone updated column K I want the datestamp to be placed on Column A on their respective sheet so far I have not been able to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is possible.  Here is some working code.  I am not exactly sure what you want to find with the regular expression so you will need to change that line.

```
function onEdit() {

  //declarations
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var regExp = "/.*?\.$/";
  var repArray  = new Array();
  var columnNumberToWatch;
  var sheet;
  var range;
  var targetCell;

  //used my own regex for testing
  //note sure what your expression needed to search for
  regExp = "name"

  //create array of sheets that match reg-exp
  for (var i in allSheets) {                              
    if ((allSheets[i].getName()).match(regExp)) {
      repArray.push(allSheets[i].getName());
    }
  }

  //if a rep sheet was changed in a certain column then 
  //put the current date in column A in the last used row
  columnNumberToWatch = 11;
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  // array.indexOf(string) returns the index if the string is found
  // if the string is not found it will return a value of -1
  if (repArray.indexOf(sheet.getName()) > -1 && range.getColumn() === columnNumberToWatch) {
    targetCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    targetCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy"));
  }

  //the function will exit at the return statement;
  return;
  //old code with the for loop was left in case you want it
  //the code was modified so it works now

  var sheetNameToWatch;
  //loop through sheets in rep-array
  for (var j in repArray) {
    sheetNameToWatch = ss.getSheetByName(repArray[j]).getName();
    columnNumberToWatch = 11;
    sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    range = sheet.getActiveCell();
    Logger.log(sheetNameToWatch+columnNumberToWatch+sheet.getName()+range.getA1Notation());
    //if a rep sheet was changed in a certain column then 
    //put the current date in column A in the last used row
    if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch) {
      targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1);
      targetCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yy"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Patrick Neugebauer I tried the code but its not working... it kinda does not do anything, and... what the expression is looking for is any sheet that includes a period if no period then no need to add the sheet to the array

Comment: Cool it works yeah that is what it was supposed to be doing the date should go in the first column where the change was made